# How to backup and compress quick rotating files to a remote server

Tags: linux, centos, backup, compression

I have a server application creating log files and rotating these files based on size. The files are time stamped at creation. The application then deletes the oldest file when *X* number of files in the directory is reached.

The application is not capable of compressing, only rotation and deletion.

The files are rotating rapidly and I need to be able to pull the files off from a remote server and compress them as quickly as possible due to space constraints on the storage server.

EDIT:  Due to resource limitations, I do not want to compress on the application server.

I have looked into `rsync` but based on the requirement to compress immediately after the file transfer to the storage server, `rsync` does not seem to fit the requirements. Can anyone suggest an alternative?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you compress them _before_ transferring them?  `gzip` all but the most recent file, then `rsync -a *.gz host:/path/to/logs`.

Comment: No, sorry I should have mentioned that I do not want to compress on the application server because I want to keep resource utilization at a minimum, network bandwidth is not a concern.